# Timeout a service

Tags: systemd, timeout

Is there a way to have systemd stop a service after it has been running for X amount of seconds?

I looked at just wrapping `ExecStart` with `timeout`, however I believe it might not work if my service is the `forking` type.

Comment: What Operating System you are referring to?

Comment: I haven't had time to play with this enough to produce a solution but my gut says there's a solution within these options: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html